# Unable to access docker container from the port mapped by docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, yeoman

I have created a docker container but unable to run it on the port mapped by the docker (http://localhost:3000).  Below are the details of docker configurations that I am using in my app.

Docker version : 17.05.0-ce

Os : ubuntu 16.04

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:boron
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY   . /usr/src/app

RUN     npm install -g bower 
RUN     npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN     npm install 
RUN     bower install --allow-root
#RUN     grunt --force
EXPOSE 3000
CMD     ["grunt", "serve"]
```

Creating docker container:

```
docker build -t viki76/ng-app .
```

Running Container:

```
docker run  -p 3000:3000 -d viki76/ng-app
```

docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND       CREATED    STATUS     PORTS  

21541171d884   viki/ng-app   "grunt serve"  10 min ago Up    0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
```

EDIT:

Updated Dockerfile configuration

```
EXPOSE 9000
```

$ docker run  -p 9000:9000  viki76/ng-app

```
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 1 path cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
Copied 2 files

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2017-05-17 13:00:13 UTC-0)
loading tasks               189ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 88%
loading grunt-contrib-copy   11ms  ▇▇ 5%
copy:styles                  16ms  ▇▇▇ 7%
Total 216ms

Running "postcss:server" (postcss) task
>> 2 processed stylesheets created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

From Gruntfile.js

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    livereload: 35729
  },
```

Please help me to fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that grunt is binding to localhost:9000 - which is internal to the container so the port you're publishing won't have any effect.

It needs to be listening on 0.0.0.0:9000 - I couldn't tell you off hand what your `Gruntfile.js` should say for that to happen, but off-hand it looks like, out of the box, grunt serve will only serve from localhost.

Comment: // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        livereload: 35729
      }
I have changed localhost to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Ah, that's great (probably worth editing your question again to include that).
Does the problem continue? If so, what happens if you try `curl http://your-server-name:9000`?

Comment: I just updated my question.
curl http://localhost:9000
output:
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Ok, and having added the `hostname: '0.0.0.0'` when you do `docker run` what does `connect:livereload` now say? I.e. it said previously `Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000`, but now it says what?

Comment: It is saying the same Started connect web server on  http://localhost:9000
I got your point. I will fix it.

Comment: It was taking image from cache. I removed that image and rebuilt it.
Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everyhthing right, though I'm assuming that your problem is simply configuration.

By default, `grunt-serve` serves on port 9000, not 3000. Do you want to try and `EXPOSE` and publish that port?

Comment: I updated my configuration with "EXPOSE 9000" and tried running app on 9000 port but It didn't work. Please check my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the container in Host mode:

```
--net="host"
```

Pass the above when you run the container.